# Checking if function parameters are not empty, in a different way using php

Tags: php

I noticed that almost in every PHP function with parameters that I've written, starts with the following line:

```
if ( ! $first_parameter || ! $second_parameter ){
      return false;
}
```

My question is a bit weird.
I would love to replace this with another type of expression, something similar to an operand because I know that a function wouldn't do

Example with a function (that doesn't work):

```
require_parameters( $first_parameter, $second_parameter );
```

however even if `require_paremeters` returned false, it wouldn't return false from the original function

would it be possible to write a function or maybe a C extension for PHP to do something similar to this:

```
require_parameters $first_parameter, $second_parameter;
```

that would return false from the original function if one of them was empty.

Thank you.

Comment: try `isset($first_parameter)`

Comment: it doesn't return false from the original function

Comment: empty() would work except in cases where you explicitly wanted to use 0, FALSE, or an empty string.

Comment: Everyone seems to be misunderstanding his question. he's not asking how to test the parameters, he's asking how to avoid having to write `return false` in his function and have it be done automatically by the testing function.

Comment: And the simple answer is that there's no way to do this. PHP doesn't have macros.

Comment: Why do you need to do this in so many of your functions? Why don't you just call your functions with correct arguments, so you don't have to check them all the time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is technically impossible.

To return false from the original function, you have to explicitly use the return statement - no going around that.

In your example, you will need to use:

```
return require_parameters( $first_parameter, $second_parameter );
```

But the definition of require_parameters will have to use varargs as you never know how many arguments you might require.

And, since PHP does not appear to handle varargs directly, you will need to use `func_get_args()` and `func_num_args()` to check each received arg if it's set. Docs can be found [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-arg.php).

*Update: as Jad pointed out, the error here is that this function will return regardless of outcome. Unfortunately, there is no way (that I know of) to simplify the following, however we can use short-circuit logic to make the check a lot shorter than using a full-blown `if`:*

**Update:** My bad, return won't work after an `or`. We can't go any simpler than this, I'm afraid.

```
if (!require_parameters( $first_parameter, $second_parameter )) return false;
```

Comment: This will return from the function even if the parameters ARE set. He only wants to return when the parameters aren't set.

Comment: @Barmar it depends on implementation of `require_parameters`.

Comment: @Barmar, this will return whatever the `require_parameters()` pleases to return. In our case, if any of it's params is unset, it will return false - and that will bubble up to the caller, which will also return false.

Comment: yes exactly! is there a way not to return true and continue with the original function if they do exist?

Comment: this technically solves the problem! But I tried it and it gives me an error, here `unexpected T_RETURN` check the pastebin link: http://pastebin.com/TNSrQHFt

Comment: You can't put `return` after `or`. `return` is a statement, the arguments to `or` must be expressions.

Comment: okay so it's technically impossible to do that in PHP. Can you update your answer saying that it doesn't work in PHP so I mark it as the correct answer. Too bad I got downvoted, I was only checking if it works

Comment: @JadJoubran, it's in the first line of the answer. Shall I make it even more explicit?

Comment: no it's great, I just wanted to accept the correct answer for other people reading this question. Thank you

Comment: @JadJoubran thanks to you as well. It's been a pleasure.